# How to dynamically bind data sources for API requests in loopback

Tags: node.js, rest, express, datasource, loopbackjs

Here is scenario wherein the different api requests have to query different databases dynamically based on the origin of the request. For instance an api request has to query users table in db1 simultaneously another api or the same api with a different origin context has to query users table from db2. This can be achieved for all routes except the default ones exposed by loopback. 
I need a solution to dynamically bind dataSources to the default apis exposed by loopback keeping in mind it is a single threaded application so that binding the dataSource to an api should not in anyway affect the behavior of the other apis that are parallelly being served by the application.

Comment: Datasources are linked to models at boot time.  The only way I could see this being feasible is if you duplicated the models at boot time at attached them to their separate datasources, then create a remote method to decide which which datasources to send it to.

Comment: Boot separate loopback process for the data sources on the fly & make HTTP requests!! Crazy enough?

Comment: @icecream_hobbit that's a good way. Actually i'm able to dynamically bind datasources to models the issue is with the default rest apis that are exposed by loopback. i'm not able to dynamically bind datasources with the default apis

Comment: @explorer you are asking me to create separate loopback instances for each datasource?

Comment: @SachinS Ignore my comment. icecream_hobbit approach is neat.

Comment: @SachinS  `i'm able to dynamically bind datasources to models the issue is with the default rest apis that are exposed by loopback.`

You wont be able to do this without affecting the other endpoints since they are accessing the same model.  

`i'm not able to dynamically bind datasources with the default apis`

The default endpoints are normal models, you can bind them just like a custom one.  Can you edit your question with your working code?

Comment: @SachinS could you please clarify what do you mean by "default REST APIs"? Are you talking about built-in models like User, AccessToken, etc.? Does I understand it correctly that you would like to attach User model to different datasource depending on incoming request?

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš , say i create a model shop, loopback provide APis like 
localhost:3000/shop = > this is what i meant by default apis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a co-author and one of the current maintainers of LoopBack.*

My advice is to create one LoopBack application for each database and write a custom Express middleware that will route API requests to the right LoopBack application.

To prevent interaction between these per-database application instances, it's crucial to enable undocumented "local registry" mode, where each application has its own local registry of models. (By default, LoopBack uses a global model registry.)

Please note this feature is not widely used, you may run into edge cases that don't work. You may end up debugging loopback internals and sending a pull request to fix those problems. (It has already happened for one or two users in the past, therefore most issues should be fixed by now.)

```
const app = loopback({localRegistry: true});
```

The code above will create a new LoopBack application that does not share any global state and does not have any built-in models configured (no User, AccessToken, etc.)

This works well for `loopback-boot` which loads exactly those built-in models that are configured in `server/model-config.json`. If you load models manually from code, you will probably want to pre-load all built-in models to your app. This can be achieved via `loadBuiltinModels` option:

```
const app = loopback({localRegistry: true, loadBuiltinModels: true});
```

Now that we know how to create an app that does not share any global state, we need to create a registry of LoopBack applications, one for each database (this can be done lazily on the first access). I'll leave this part as an exercise for the reader. The only important part is to mount `loopback.rest()` middleware on each per-database application, otherwise we won't be able to implement request handling later.

```
const app = loopback({localRegistry: true, loadBuiltinModels: true});
app.use(loopback.rest());
```

With the registry of LoopBack applications in place, we can write Express middleware to handle requests:

```
function handleApiRequest(req, res, next) {
  const app = // obtain the LoopBack application instance to use
  app(req, res, next);
}

// use the middleware in your root application, e.g.
const app = express();
app.use(cors({/*...*/});
app.use(handleApiRequest);
app.use(errorHandler({/*...*/});
```

Comment: I followed your approach to creating different loopback applications. But then I came across loopback-context. It almost solved my problem as in this is the solution I wanted. Now the last difficulty I'm facing is that I'm losing the context at times, and at times incorrect context is being passed during concurrency. Any suggestions on this subject?

Comment: @SachinS loopback-context is using continuation-local-storage under the hood, and CLS is known to be broken - the issue you are facing are sort of expected. The situation may have improved in Node.js 8.x with the introduction of async_hooks, but I don't know what's the exact status.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. Will definitely work on that

Comment: @SachinS did you achieve this if yes then how can you post all logic that you has been used to create this

Comment: Folks, would you mind to upvote my answer if you find it useful?